# How do I get rss feed link from blog in jQuery

Tags: jquery, rss, feed

hi friends is there a way following that I can get blog rss url by giving url of the blog.
For example if I provide http://googleblog.blogspot.com the output should be http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss or other if change for another blog.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution by using google feed API

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/lookup?v=1.0&q=http://www.bbcurdu.com

will return feed links for http://www.bbcurdu.com

Answer (score 0):

```
var discoverFeedUrlFor = function(pageURL) {
var baseApiUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/lookup?v=1.0";
var jQueryJsonpToken = "&callback=?"; // tells jQuery to treat it as JSONP request
var pageUrlParameter = "&q=" + pageURL;

var requestUrl = baseApiUrl + jQueryJsonpToken + pageUrlParameter;

return $.getJSON(requestUrl);
};

discoverFeedUrlFor("http://wordpress.com")
.done(function(data) {
var queryResult = data.responseData;
if (!!queryResult) {
var feedUrl = queryResult.url;
console.log(feedUrl);
}
});
```